# regression results summary takes so long that makes me really confusing?

Tags: r, stargazer, plm

I am currently working on panel data (using the `plm` package) with around 10 variables and only 30.000 observations. When I turn the option in `plm()` command from  `effect = "individual"` to `effect = "twoways"`, the calculation time takes ca. 1 minute, which I still find OK, and I got a plm object with a size of 12MB.

However, when I summarize the regression result with either `summary(plm.object)` or `stargazer(plm.object)`, the process time can take up to 15 minutes with a CPU intensive work, which makes me really really confusing! From my understanding, the regression result is already stored in the plm.object after the regression, the only thing summary or stargazer does is show the result from the plm object.

Does anyone have an idea why `summary()` takes so long time?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say it's taking so long because [of this](https://github.com/cran/plm/blob/a8e5d802b36d3d78baa2f2e2a98c67519eb959da/R/plm.methods.R#L24) or [this](https://github.com/cran/plm/blob/a8e5d802b36d3d78baa2f2e2a98c67519eb959da/R/plm.methods.R#L25).

Comment: Thanks, @RomanLuštrik.  If that is the case, any idea I can turn it off. All I need is to see the regression results.

Comment: First you could profile this function to see where the bottlenecks are. Without digging any further all I can recommend is to calculate summary results once, store them into an object and print that.

Comment: Are you passing a function for the argument `vcov` to `summary()`? Non-default standard errors take some time to calculate albeit 15 mins sounds too long. Any chance to make the data set and your code for estimation available?

Comment: The estimated coefficients are stored in the plm object but not t-statistics, p-values, model statistics (those are stored in the object `summary()` generates).

Comment: You can run `pwaldtest(plm.object)` by hand to check @RomanLuštrik suggestion if the calculation of the F statistic take such a long time. (The other suggestion, `model <- describe(object, "model")` is really just a quick extraction of the model type estimated.)

Comment: Thanks, @Helix123!  I guess it's the main reason if t-value and P-value were generated by the  `summary()`.  In addition, I tried your suggestion using `describe(object, "model")` but I got the error: `Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 'x' must be atomic`.

Comment: So the run time of `pwaldtest(plm.object)` is "short"? Using `describe()` was not my suggestion, if you want to run it, you will need to use `plm::describe(plm.object)` as that function is not exported from package plm - still, this function does not much and thus won't be the cause for the long run time of `summary()`.

Comment: `pwaldtest` run time is very short within secs.

Comment: The calculation of t-statistics and p-values should be fast as well... unless you supply a function to the argument `vcov`, then it could take a while... but you did not comment on my earlier comment about it.